# How to point to/get the file contents or file from sharepoint changes api call

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-api

I am using sharepoint rest api `/getchanges` to get changes in a sharepoint site and obtain results as :-

```
{
    "d": {
        "results": [{
            "__metadata": {
                "id": "https://mysite.sharepoint.com/test/_api/SP.ChangeItem38931e4b-01fa-4744-b478-e4f2b7cd7d8c",
                "uri": "https://mysite.sharepoint.com/test/_api/SP.ChangeItem38931e4b-01fa-4744-b478-e4f2b7cd7d8c",
                "type": "SP.ChangeItem"
            },
            "ChangeToken": {
                "__metadata": {
                    "type": "SP.ChangeToken"
                },
                "StringValue": "1;1;16393f71-acfe-4ff4-a8e2-5668f572d3c6;636035775676900000;17124328"
            },
            "ChangeType": 1,
            "SiteId": "16393f71-acfe-4ff4-a8e2-5668f572d3c6",
            "Time": "2016-07-08T12:26:07Z",
            "Editor": "",
            "EditorEmailHint": null,
            "ItemId": 21,
            "ListId": "244dcdb3-d056-4184-aa21-1dc7f507f199",
            "ServerRelativeUrl": "",
            "SharedByUser": null,
            "SharedWithUsers": null,
            "WebId": "9eb4d645-db81-4e3b-b2c1-cecc0b4efe5f"
        }]
    }
}
```

The request I've used is :-

`POST` http://mysite.sharepoint.com/test/_api/site/getchanges
    with json body as change query :-

```
  {
  'query': {
    '__metadata': {
      'type': 'SP.ChangeQuery'
    }, 
    'Update': true, 'Add': true,'Item':true,'DeleteObject':true
  }
}
```

Now I would like to get the contents out of these changes if it is a file change. But I cannot relate the Id obtained in the result WebId or ItemId to the file id that can be obtained using files and folders api of sharepoint. So how can I relate this result to the actual file id or file to get the contents of changed file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From further research I found out that we can get the file contents by calling :-

```
GET https://mysite.sharepoint.com/<site_name>/_api/web/lists(guid'<list-id>')/items(<item-id>)/File
```

api of sharepoint using list id and item id obtained from `/getchanges` api. Then use the ***ServerRelativeUrl*** field of response to obtain file contents by calling :-

```
GET http://mysite.sharepoint.com/<site_name>/_api/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('<url>)/$value?binaryStringResponseBody=true
```

Cheers :)